# Implicit Intent to a non built-in app

Tags: android, android-intent, panoramas

I am new to Android development.
I need to build a simple app which calls another app after the button is pressed.

To put things more clearly.
I need a button press to call an intent which opens a panorama capture application.
I my case [360 panorama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vtcreator.android360).

However when I referred to [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html) document, it says we must verify whether the app has a receiving intent. I don't understand how to do that.

Also if this is possible.. That is opening 360 Panorama, is it also possible that once I click the button in my app, the capture starts automatically without actually pressing the capture button in 360 Panorama?

Answer (score 1):

To check if an activity installed on your device can receive the intent, use something like this:

```
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }   else  {
        Log.d(TAG, "No activity available to handle Intent.");
    }
```

Comment: I am getting an error cannot resolve symbol for packageManager as well as TAG. Alt+Enter does not import required libraries. Do I need to declare package manager and other things inside any method?

Comment: `packageManager` is simply an instance from `getPackageManager()`, and TAG is the string that you use to identify the source of the message. It is good practice to declare a constant `TAG` to use with error logging, but in this case replacing it with the String name of your app would work.

Comment: If I helped, select the green check next to my answer please! :)

Answer (score 0):

> I need a button press to call an intent which opens a panorama
>   capture application. I my case 360 panorama.

Yes, this is possible. You can obviously open any app you want provided, you know its package name. In this case, you must be knowing the package name of 360 panorama app. So this is very much possible.

You can do something like this,

```
final Intent intentDeviceTest = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");                
intentDeviceTest.setComponent(new ComponentName("fm.last.android","fm.last.android.LastFm"));
startActivity(intentDeviceTest);
```

This will open the lastfm app. Ensure that you surround it in a **try/catch block** and check for `ActivityNotFoundException` so that your app doesn;t crash if the 3rd party app is not installed.

> That is opening 360 Panorama, is it also possible that once I click
>   the button in my app, the capture starts automatically without
>   actually pressing the capture button in 360 Panorama?

The possibility solely depends on how the 3rd party app, in this case 360 panorama is designed.

It must able to receive the Intent and start the capture automatically and send the captured image to your app where in your `onActivityResult()` method. Remember to use `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()`

This is not in your control. The simple answer is, **if the 3rd party app allows this, you can surely do it**, and if not, then there is no way to use that 3rd party app for that purpose.

Comment: Do you need any more help regarding this? If this solved your problem, then please consider upvoting and accepting it.